# MobilePush in Journey Builder accepting data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush

I'm in the middle of creating a Journey in Journey Builder that will send a push message based off data that I am firing in to my API Event.

In my Payload I have

```
"Data": {
        "CONTACTID":"sandeep",
        "PUSH_CONTENT":"This is some sample push data"
}
```

and what I want to do is to include %%PUSH_CONTENT%% in my Mobile Push message - but whenever I do it doesn't want to work.

Anything I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - this is not possible with the out-of-the-box MobileConnect and MobilePush activities for Journey Builder. I went ahead and created my own custom activity to get around the issue.

Comment: Hello, did you try using GTL ? I am having the same issue and I prefer not to use custom activities for this use case.